# for loop a dictionary with items having similar and different values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

In python 3, why does "for looping" a dictionary with items having similar and different values gives different result? Example is given below:

```
>>> A = 0
>>> B = 0
>>> for i in {A, B}:
    print (i)
0
>>> A = 1
>>> B = 1
>>> for i in {A, B}:
    print (i)
1
>>> A = 0
>>> B = 1
>>> for i in {A, B}:
    print (i)
0
1
```

Comment: it's not a dictionary, it's a `set`, and since your values are equal, `set` keeps only one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this `{A,B}` syntax is not a dictionary syntax, it's a `set`, and when your values are equal, `set` keeps only one of them, since `set` is designed to guarantee uniqueness of items (but not their order)

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a dictionary you're iterating through, it's a `set`. Set literals are created using comma separated values inside curly brackets `{A, B, ...}`.

Dictionaries are created by colon separated values inside square brackets `{A: valueA, B: valueB}`. Irregardless you'd still get the same result with a dictionary, since you can't have duplicate keys and, as such, if `A` and `B` have the same value only a single key is going to exist.